# HttpEndpoint and Proxy Options in Vert.x

Tags: vert.x, service-discovery

I am working on Vert.x Service Discovery registering HttpEndPoints. Is there a way to specify ProxyOptions when publishing HttpEndPoint to service discovery?

Thanks,
-Rajani

Comment: vertx 3.4 has it http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-discovery/java/

Comment: Hi Niraj, My question is very specific on how to add Proxy configuration to HttpClient returned by ServiceReference from Service Discovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide the options when creating the record but when retrieving the service reference.

```
ServiceReference reference = discovery.getReferenceWithConfiguration(record, new HttpClientOptions()
        .setProxyOptions(proxyOptions)
        .toJson());
```

This explained in the [retrieving a service reference](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-discovery/java/#_retrieving_a_service_reference) section of the documentation:

> When retrieving a service reference you can pass a JsonObject used to
>   configure the service object.